# Dependency injection in uitableviewcell nibs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dependency-injection, swift3

I'm trying to build a pretty complex table. One cell of this table imports another table. In this imported table I show different rows depending on the situation. The imported table and all the importable table cells are organized into own nib files with own controllers for every cell. As a good programmer I'm trying to use dependency injection throughout the project. The problem now is that when I use the usual way of registering the nibs in viewDidLoad()

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionCell")
```

and then use them as dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:) in tableView(tableView: cellForRowAt:)

```
let batchConsumptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionCell
batchConsumptionCell.setConsumption(consumption: consumption)
return batchConsumptionCell
```

I'm not able to inject the dependencies in time.

In the BatchConsumptionCell all I do in tableView(tableView: cellForRowAt:) works fine. This function is called after dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:) is executed. But as soon as I'm trying to make the tableView(tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:) dynamic I run into problems. This functions seems to be called before dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:) so the dependencies are not injected at this point.

I tried to override the init(nibName: bundle:) initializer in my BatchConsumptionCell, but this is a UITableViewCell so I was not able to override this.

How do I approach this? Is there any way I could inject the dependencies as the nib and its controller are initialized? Or do I organize my cells all wrong? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

For more clarity here is my code:

**ConsumptionDetailViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ConsumptionDetailViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties

var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!

var consumption: Consumption!


// MARK: - Outlet Properties

@IBOutlet weak var labelDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTime: UILabel!
...


// MARK: - Default Methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionCell")

    updateTableFields(selectedConsumption: consumption)
}


// MARK: - UI Update Methods

func updateTableFields(selectedConsumption: Consumption) {

    labelId.text = selectedConsumption.wtId
    ...
}

// MARK: - BatchAddEditDelegate Methods

func didFinishEditing(consumption: Consumption) {
    updateTableFields(selectedConsumption: consumption)
}

// MARK: - TableView Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        let batchConsumptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionCell
        batchConsumptionCell.setConsumption(consumption: consumption)
        return batchConsumptionCell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
}


// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    ...
}

}
```

**BatchConsumptionCell**

```
import UIKit

class BatchConsumptionCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var consumption: Consumption!
var batchConsumptionCount: Int!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    var cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell")

    cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell")

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

func setConsumption(consumption: Consumption) {
    self.consumption = consumption
    self.batchConsumptionCount = consumption.batchConsumptions?.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if batchConsumptionCount == 1 { // <-- This does not work
        return 3
    } else {
        return batchConsumptionCount
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if batchConsumptionCount == 1 { // <-- This works fine
        let batchConsumptionBasicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionBasicCell
        let bc = consumption.batchConsumptions?.allObjects[0] as! BatchConsumption
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Batch", detail: (bc.batch?.wtId)!)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Weight", detail: String(describing: bc.weight!))
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Price", detail: String(format:"%.2f", bc.price))
        }
    } else if batchConsumptionCount >= 2 {
        let batchConsumptionMultiCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionMultiCell
        return batchConsumptionMultiCell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

}
```

See the comments `// <-- This works fine` and
// `<-- This does not work` in BatchConsumptionCell

Comment: Show your code for `setConsumumption`

Comment: and also where to update batchConsumptionCount value?

Comment: Sorry, forgot setConsumption(consumption:) in BatchConsumptionCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also register nib to the BatchConsumptionCell class, and implement necessary table view's data source & delegate methods:

```
class BatchConsumptionCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var consumption: Consumption!
    var batchConsumptionCount: Int!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        var cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell")

        cellNib = UINib(nibName: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell")

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func setConsumption(consumption: Consumption) {
        self.consumption = consumption
        self.batchConsumptionCount = consumption.batchConsumptions?.count
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return consumption == nil ? 0 : 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if batchConsumptionCount == .some(1) { return 3 }
        return batchConsumptionCount ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch batchConsumptionCount {
        case .some(1):
            let batchConsumptionBasicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionBasicCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionBasicCell
            let bc = consumption.batchConsumptions?.allObjects[0] as! BatchConsumption
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Batch", detail: (bc.batch?.wtId)!)
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Weight", detail: String(describing: bc.weight!))
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                batchConsumptionBasicCell.configure(title: "Price", detail: String(format:"%.2f", bc.price))
            }
            return batchConsumptionBasicCell

        default:
            let batchConsumptionMultiCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BatchConsumptionMultiCell", for: indexPath) as! BatchConsumptionMultiCell
            return batchConsumptionMultiCell

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have done that. The BatchConsumptionCell looks pretty much as you suggested. The header is `class BatchConsumptionCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` and I load the cells exactly as you sead with `let nib = UINib(...` and `tableView.register(...` but where do I inject my dependencies into this BatchConsumptionCell???

Comment: What do you mean "inject my dependencies"? Would you please paste your entire BatchConsumptionCell code on your question?

Comment: Inside my BatchConsumptionCell I need the var `consumption`. At the moment I set this var via `batchConsumptionCell.setConsumption(consumption: consumption)` after I loaded it with `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:)` (see above). But when I try to set the number of rows depending on this injected var in `tableView(tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:)` I get a error. `tableView(tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:)` seems to be called before I can set my `consumption` var.

Comment: I updated the question for more details. BTW, thank you very much for your help bubuxu 

Comment: Ueee, reloading the whole table data with `var consumption: Consumption! {
        didSet {
            batchConsumptionCount = consumption.batchConsumptions?.count
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }` did the trick.

Comment: Tank you very much bubuxu, you just made my day 

Comment: the method of **tableView.reloadData()** did the trick actually. And you don't need to set batchConsumptionCount as get / set property, you can just define it as a readonly property: `var batchConsumptionCount: Int? { return consumption.batchConsumptions?.count }`.